# Как в Prettier отключить перенос строки после запятой?

Tags: prettier, linter

Установил prettier глобально.

В корне проекта настроил конфиг.
Когда я сохраняю файл и prettier автоматически форматирует его, то вот это:

```
ul, li, ol { margin: 0 }
```

Превращается в это:

```
ul,
li,
ol { margin: 0; }
```

Как убрать перенос строки после запятой? Беда в том, что если перечисления хотя бы больше 5, становится не удобно читать.

Как оформить перенос, например после нескольких тегов?

Comment: Либо есть [нужная опция](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), либо [никак](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html).

Comment: Да, читал документацию, думал может есть всё таки способ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут уже написали что prettier специально имеет мало настроек, но если очень хочется что-то поменять самый простой споб это [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint). Эта штука автоматически запускает eslint fix после prettier, все дополнительные правила форматирования далее настраиваются в еслинте.

Comment: Балдёж. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: без стороннего вмешательства в Prettier - никак.

Prettier пропагандирует философию единого оформления кода для всех и отсутствие дебатов по этому поводу, поэтому настроек не так много.

И пожалуй, это даже хорошо.